# Rendering in Angular with object prototype methods in the template

Tags: angular, render

I would like to know if when using these methods or properties that come from Object Prototype inheritance, such as:

```js
value.substring(0, 5)
value.toString()
```

Using in templates:

```html
<div>{{value.substring(0, 5)}}</div>
```

Using it in the template creates an unnecessary rendering cycle, as using methods in the template creates this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular class level property

```js
<div>{{valueToDisplay}}</div>

public valueToDisplay: string;

private update(value: string): void {
   this.valueToDisplay = value.substring(0, 5);
}
```

Or alternatively, create an Angular `pipe` that takes in the `value`, and returns the `substring` of that `value`

Comment: But these methods with `toString()` and `substring()`, cause unnecessary rendering?